# Beginner at C++. Get errors in the code

Tags: c++

I am completely new to c++, but I tried to run a code from a book I am reading about the subject. It is a very basic book for beginners, but it contains som codes which I have tried to write into c++ to learn how it works. I tried the following code, but I get two errors:

In function 'int main()':

[Error] expected ';' before 'emp'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

class Employee
{
    private:
        int m_id;
    public:
        Employee(){}
        Employee(int id)
        {
            m_id=id;
        }
        int id;
        std::string firstname;
        std::string lastname;
        int birthyear;

        void ClockTime()
        {
            //clocktime code goes here
        }

        ~Employee()
        {
             m_id=0;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Employee emp(2);
    std::cout<<"The employee time clocked is"
    emp.ClockTime()<<std::endl;     
    return 0;   
}
```

Is there much I have to change in order for this code to work?

Comment: C++ error messages can be a bit weird - you left out a semicolon on the line above when you typed it in. (Or there's a typo in the book.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You broke a line while printing. It should be:

```
std::cout<<"The employee time clocked is " <<
emp.ClockTime()<<std::endl;
```

Remember that white-space characters are ignored by the C++ compiler. So in your version, you had something like this:

```
std::cout<<"The employee time clocked is"emp.ClockTime()<<std::endl;
```

Which should make it clear to you why the error happens.

---

As [**gurka**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/969365/gurka) points out, you have numerous other problems with your code. Not the least of which is that you can't print a `void` (can't do much with it as a matter of fact). So `ClockTime` should return something.

Comment: Also `ClockTime()` returns void and I don't think there is a `std::basic_ostream::operator<<` overload that accepts void?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have inserted what you wrote above, but then I god the following error:  [Error] no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'void')

Comment: @David see my comment above.

Comment: Thanks to both gurka and Story Teller! I deleted the "void" before ClockTime, and now it gave me a result. Thanks!

Comment: @David: You have to replace `void` with something else, something meaningful. Don't just delete it.